# output clause returns value but executescalar returns null in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, executescalar

I need to get the updated row's first column value. However when I run query `Update ClaimDetails set sStatus='False' OUTPUT inserted.slno as Slno where inVoiceNo='******' and sStatus='True'`

 in Management Studio it returns the right value. But when I try to get the value using `Executescalar()` it returns null

My code:

```
 bool isupdated = false;
        int modified=0;
        try
        {

            string updateqry = "Update ClaimDetails set sStatus=@sStatus OUTPUT inserted.slno as Slno where inVoiceNo=@inVoiceNo and sStatus='True'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateqry, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sStatus", sStatus);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inVoiceNo", inVoiceNo);
            connect();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                isupdated = true;
                 //modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                object a = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (a != null)
                    modified = Convert.ToInt32(a);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
        finally { disconnect(); }
        return modified;
```

When I used `modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` it gave me an exception error so I used `object`

Comment: " it gave me an exception error" what exception did it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is executing the same `UPDATE` command twice, once with ExecuteNonQuery (which discards the scalar result and returns the count of rows affected) and again with ExecuteScalar. Because of the hard-coded 'True' in the `WHERE` clause, the second invocation of same command will never update a row when the provided `sStatus` value is 'False'.  The scalar result will always be `null` in that case.

I think you can refactor the code as below to get the desired result.

```
object a = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (a != null)
{
    isupdated = true;
    modified = Convert.ToInt32(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time that `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` is if *no rows* are returned. If one row is returned and the value *is* `null`, then `DbNull.Value` is returned instead.

So: no rows are matching. Check what `@inVoiceNo` is, and whether or not it exists in the table you're running against. Common reasons for confusion:

- case sensitivity in the database
- unicode vs ascii/code-page values
- char vs varchar, nchar vs nvarchar
- running against the wrong data

Comment: I ran same query in Management Studio, and it gave me right result ie; `44019' which is right

Comment: @mark so now you need to debug it. Forget everything you think you know about the values of the parameters and the state of the database - and indeed, which database you think you're talking to. Check *everything*

Answer (score 0):

in case someone want the actual number of records on update not just handling the null value ,,
in the stored procedure our DB developer set ***return*** @@ROWCOUNT [typo] instead ***SELECT*** @@ROWCOUNT